# Evaluating high level algorithm fitness to an embedded platform

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, embedded, real-time

What is the process you would consider to evaluate high level algorithm (mainly computer vision algorithms, written in Matlab, python etc.) to run real time on an embedded CPU.

The idea is to have a reliable assessment/calculations at early stage when you cannot implement or profile it on the target HW.

To put things in focus lets assume that your input is a grayscale QVGA frame, 8bpp @ 30fps and you have to perform a full canny edge detection on each and every input frame. How can we find or estimate the minimum processing power needed to perform this successfully?

Comment: What is your concept of an "embedded CPU". Are we talking micro-controller class or smart-phone class?

Comment: This is far too broad without specific systems in mind.

Comment: Suppose we need to implement on a micro controller with ARM Cortex A53 core. But regardless of the actual micro controller core - I would like to have a generic assessment process that can be applied to any micro controller

Comment: @SeanCV Well, you need to study microcontrollers then, because the difference between a Cortex A53 and some 8 bit PIC is astronomic. Even is you are only looking at high-end microcontrollers, they are all very different in terms of clock, instruction set, cache use, cores etc etc.

Comment: Another point that was unclear to me. Do you intend to re-code the "high level algorithm" into a natively compiled language or were you intending to run the Matlab, python, etc. implementation? The choice has dramatic impact on the type of computing platform required.

Answer (score 1):

A generic assessment isn't quite possible and what you request is tedious manual work.

There are however a few generic steps you could follow to arrive at a rough idea

1. Estimate the run-time complexity of your algorithm in terms of basic math operations like additions and multiplications (best/average/worst ? your choice). 
   Do you need floating point support? 
    Also track high level math operations like saturating add/subtract (Why ? see point 3).
2. Devour the ISA of the target processor and focus especially on the math and branching instructions. 
   How many cycles does a multiplication take? Or, does your processor dispatch several per cycle ?
3. See if your processor supports features like,

   - Saturating math. 
     ARM Cortex-M4 does. PIC18 micro-controller does not, incurring additional execution overhead.
   - Hardware floating point operations.
   - Branch prediction.
   - SIMD.
     Will provide significant speed boost if your algorithm could be tailored to it.
4. Since you explicitly asked for a `CPU`, see if yours has a `GPU` attached. Image processing algorithms generally benefit from the presence of one.
5. Map your operations (from step 1) to what the target processor supports (in step 3) to arrive at an estimate.
6. Other factors (out of a zillion other) that you need to take into account

   - Do you plan to run an OS on the target or is it bare-bone ?
   - Is your algorithm bound by IO bottlenecks ?
   - If your processor has a cache, how efficient is your algorithm in utilizing it ?